# Android - PhoneGap Native Controls

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm new to Android and PhoneGap developing and I need to write an application for both the iPhone and Android.

I'm currently stuck on creating a native menu for the Android using PhoneGap. I have the native tab bar menu working for on the iOS using PhoneGap.

Question 1)
Where can I find some examples or plugins that use a native tab bar menu for the android?

Question 2)
Debating creating the menu using HTML5/CSS/jQuery.  What are the pros and cons of using PhoneGap native controls vs sticking with HTML5?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use a tab bar menu on an Android project. Instead you should use a Context menu. Actually for all your menu needs you should try out Michael's new plugin where you use the menu tag and it creates the right menu depending on your OS.

https://github.com/mwbrooks/cordova-plugin-menu

Comment: Having issues installing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802399/android-phonegap-mwbrooks-cordova-plugin-menu

Comment: It seems this plugin is out of date and not of any use to newer PhoneGap versions.