# Android PhoneGap - mwbrooks / cordova-plugin-menu

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I tried installing the following plugin with no luck:
https://github.com/mwbrooks/cordova-plugin-menu

I'm using PhoneGap 1.7.0

I have the basic PhoneGap project setup and running fine (Android 4.0.3): 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

I do not fully understand how to install the plugin, but I did the following:

```
1) Copied the \native\android\src\com\ to my project \src directory.
2) Copied the \native\android\libs\phonegap-1.0.0.jar to my project \libs\phonegap-1.0.0.jar
```

When I run as -> Android Project I get the following error:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Did I install this correctly? If I did what is this error?

If not, how do I install this plugin?

Comment: I believe that the plugin is out of date and doesn't work with the latest version of PhoneGap.

Comment: You should raise an issue on the plugin to see if Michael can fix it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2) Copied the \native\android\libs\phonegap-1.0.0.jar to my project \libs\phonegap-1.0.0.jar`

`I'm using PhoneGap 1.7.0`

Pick one. Can't have both...